# How do I place buttons on top of FlakeView in Layout?

Tags: android, layout, button, android-framelayout

I'm a noob to android development and I am trying to place buttons on top of a FlakeView from the 9 Old Androids library.  As I am using a Frame Layout to place the buttons above the Layout containing the FlakeView.  However, when I run the app the buttons show behind the flakes, instead of in front of them. I used Frame Layout before to accomplish this without any problems, so i don't understand whi it isn't working now. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="More"
        android:id="@+id/more"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Less"
        android:id="@+id/less"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Game"
        android:id="@+id/newgame"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your layout organized backwards for what you are trying to accomplish.  Do the following:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

 </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="More"
    android:id="@+id/more"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Less"
    android:id="@+id/less"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Game"
    android:id="@+id/newgame"/>

</LinearLayout>



</FrameLayout>
```